# Writing HTML file path names for local files

Tags: html

Please bear with me since I am a noob at html.

Let's say I have a local directory called `website` saved inside my local Downloads folder, and inside this `website` directory I have an html file called `page.html`

Inside the `website` directory, I also have another directory called `folder`

Inside the `folder` directory, I have an html file called `page2.html`

In the html code for `page.html`, there is this line of code:
`<a href="/website/folder/page2.html">page 2</a>`

When I open `page.html` locally in a web browser, the file path name is `file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/website/page.html`.

When I then click that `page 2` link on the webpage, it brings me to `file:///website/folder/page2.html` instead of the correct path `file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/website/folder/page2.html` so it doesn't work.

I know I could change the href link in `page.html` to `file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/website/folder/page2.html` but I want this link to work even if I move the `website` directory into a different local directory. For example, the href link would work whether I have the `website` directory inside my Downloads, Desktop, or Documents folder, or even if I saved this `website` directory onto a different PC.

Is there a way to word the href link so that this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ll need to use `href="../page.html"` in your page2.html file.

I recommend you read up on [what a URL is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL), especially the part [Absolute URLs vs relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls)

So a URL has different parts, beginning with the scheme like `file` or `https`.

[image: Different parts of a URL explained. http = scheme, www.example.com = Domain Name, 80 = Port, /path/to/my/file.html = Path to the file, ?key1=value1&key2=value2 = Parameters, #SomewhereInTheDocument = Anchor]

*Image from Mozilla at the before-mentioned URLs*

You can skip certain parts at the beginning of a URL, which will give you a relative URL. These parts will be replaced by the user agent (the browser) from the current location.

For example, you can use *scheme-relative* URLs:

`<a href="//myhost.example.com/page.html">`

If the page containing that code is served via `https`, the link will also be completed to https: `https://myhost.example.com/page.html`. If it’s served via `ftp`, it will complete to `ftp://myhost.example.com/page.html`.

The same goes for other parts, and when referencing other pages from the same site, you would use *path-relative* URLs.

### Absolute and relative paths

Now, concerning the path part of a URL, there is also a distinction between *absolute paths* and *relative paths*, just like in your operating system.

`<a href="/page.html">` is using an absolute path. This means go to the root directory of the same drive or host, to find page.html.

In your case, the page2.html is delivered from `file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/website/folder/page2.html`.

So when you use a path beginning with `/` (absolute), it will refer to the root of the drive, so basically `C:\` and complete to `file:///page.html`.

`<a href="../page.html">` now is a relative path, relative to the current location. It’s saying go up one directory to find page.html.

So with the same location as before, this will complete to
`file:///Users/myuser/Downloads/website/page.html`.