# href link to current path's child

Tags: html, url, path

I'm trying to link from page `http://example.com/en/blog` to `http://example.com/en/blog/article-1337`

I want to keep the `/blog` part of the path and suffix it with the next page `article-1337`.

Example:

```html
<!-- http://example.com/en/blog -->
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<a href="/my-dog-is-4">My dog is now 4 years old</a>
<a href="/mom-left-me">Mother left me at Disney land</a>
<!-- Clicking the links above should ideally navigate to http://example.com/en/blog/my-dog-is-4 -->
```

In the HTML I've tried the following:

```html
<a href="article-1337"> - Links to http://localhost:3000/en/article-1337
<a href="/article-1337"> - Links to http://localhost:3000/article-1337
<a href="./article-1337"> - Links to http://localhost:3000/en/article-1337
<a href="../article-1337"> - Links to http://localhost:3000/article-1337
```

Is it possible to link a page like this to include the current path + article-1337 without JS?

I could do the following, but it feels dirty:

```html
<a href={window.location.pathname.split('/').pop() + '/article-1337'}>
```

The reason I want to do this is because blog will be different depending on locale, but I want to avoid adding translations to the href attribute.

Comment: A recent answer I wrote might be interesting for you as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/73269223/608042

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to link to `blog/article-1337`:

```html
<a href="blog/article-1337">…
```

Getting the blog/ part is not possible by means of HTML alone.

Using JavaScript, as you mention, is dirty for a static HTML page because it’s relying on client-side scripting for the very foundation of site navigation.

The reason why this is complicated is due to your choice of URL architecture. Would you use `/en/blog/` as the home for the blog, simply linking to `article-1337` would work.

Your folder hierarchy would be

```
/en/index.html
/en/blog/index.html
/en/blog/article-1337.html
```

But, you certainly have some generator for your HTML, you are not writing everything by hand.

So this generator handles also navigation and marking the current page as active in the navigation. It is also able to insert the current path into HTML.

For example, in PHP you could use

```php
<a href="<?= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>/article-1337">
```